# rabbitmqadmin in windows not working properly in windows

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqadmin

I download rabbitmqadmin from http://localhost:15672/cli/index.html
And I installed python and set its path.
But when I typed commands of rabbitmqadmin, not working.

python.exe rabbitmqadmin --helps
 The output is: no such option present

python.exe rabbitmqadmin 
 The output is: action not specified.

python.exe rabbitmqadmin list queue name
 The output is: Don't know how to list queue.

I don't know why its happening and I also read rabbitmq document, but not able to find its solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`python.exe rabbitmqadmin --help` is the correct command to get help.

`python.exe rabbitmqadmin` returns `action not specified` because you have not provided an action like `list queues` for it to perform. See the `--help` output as well as the output of `python.exe rabbitmqadmin help subcommands`.

Please see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/lukebakken/f8773f625e75c5e0080dea33fed29d5b) with several example commands and their output.